# Meteor: Render Vis JS Timeline Chart in the Meteor App

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, vis.js

I want to implement ViS JS Timeline Chart into my meteor app, i have downloaded the vis JS and CSS and added to the lib folder, i have created my template

```
<template name="vChart">
  <div id="visualization"></div>
</template>
```

Below i am subscribing the data

```
    Template.vChart.onCreated(function(){
      var self = this;
      self.autorun(function(){
        var uMacAdd = FlowRouter.getParam('mc');
        self.subscribe('historyinfo', uMacAdd);
      });
    });
```

On Render i call the showChart which renders my Chart, but the problem is When i fetch the data from collection, it returns null.

```
    Template.vChart.onRendered(function(){
      var historyDump= Collection.find({}).fetch();
      console.log("------------------------------------------------");
      console.log(historyDump); 
      showChart();
    });
```

Right now i am displaying hard Coded data in the chart but it should be dynamic and those data i want to fetch it from my Collection.

```
   var showChart = function(){
    var container = document.getElementById('visualization');

  // Create a DataSet (allows two way data-binding)
    var items = new vis.DataSet([
      {id: 1, className: 'Red',content: 'X', start: new Date(Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24),
      end: new Date(Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 23)},
      {id: 2, className: 'green', content: 'Y', start: new Date(Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 20),
      end: new Date(Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 19)}
    ]);

  // Configuration for the Timeline
    var options = {
      //timeAxis: {scale: 'hour'},
      zoomMax: 8.64e+7
    };

  // Create a Timeline
    var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
}
```

To Solve this i tried writing helper for Template vChart and called it from the onRender but no use.

```
Template.vChart.helpers({
    getHistory: function(){
      var historyDump= Collection.find({}).fetch();
      return historyDump;
    }
});

Template.vChart.onRendered(function(){
    var res = Template.vChart.__helpers['getHistory']();
    console.log(res);   
    showChart();
});
```

How do i achieve this ?

Note: My Subscribe and publish working properly and i could see the data in the command line. Only `Collection.find({}).fetch()` written in helper or render isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Tried Subscribe callback and it works :) No need of OnRender and no need of any helper. Please post if you have better solution than this.

```
Template.vChart.onCreated(function(){
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function(){
        var uMacAdd = FlowRouter.getParam('uMac');
        self.subscribe('historyinfo', uMacAdd, {
           onReady: function() { showChart();  },
           onError: function() { console.log('Error'); }
        });
    });
});
```